# How to combine custom psobjects with different properties

Tags: windows, powershell

I have multiple psobjects that I've made. They are all the same object types with noteproperty props. I exported the sample objects into CSV, they can be created by directly importing the file into an object

```
[psobject]$object=Import-Csv <file>.csv
```

Policy object:

```
"Type","Policy Name","Policy ENCcription","Store","Last Modified","GUID","Assigned","Polling Interval","MainMode LifeTime","Master PFS","Main Mode Security Method Order(1)","Main Mode Security Method Order(2)","Main Mode Security Method Order(3)","Main Mode Security Method Order(4)","Main Mode Security Method Order(5)","No. of Rules"
"Policy","AD DC Failsafe IPSec policy","Permits inter-DC replication traffic, AD as client....","Local Store","11/2/2017 8","{GUID}","NO","180 minutes","480 minutes / 0 Quick Mode sessions","NO","Encryption     Integrity      DH Group","3ENC          INT1          (2)","3ENC          INT5           (2)","ENC           INT1          (1)","ENC           INT5           (1)","4"
```

Rule object:

```
"Type","Rule ID","Rule Name","Rule Description","Last Modified","Activated","Connection Type","Authentication Methods(1)"
"Rule","1,  GUID = {GUID}","NONE","","11/2/2017 8","YES","ALL","KERBEROS"
```

Filter object:

```
"Type","Filter Description","Mirrored","Source IP Address","Source DNS Name","Destination IP Address","Destination Mask","Destination DNS Name","Protocol","Source Port","Destination Port"
"Filter","DC as DNS client.","YES","<My IP Address>","<My IP Address>","<A Specific IP Address>","255.255.255.255","<A Specific IP Address>","UDP","ANY","53"
```

Then end result is one object with all the properties that I can export to CSV for Excel manipulation. While I only gave you 3 objects, I have 5 object types with 197 total objects. I plan on using the process here to loop through the rest.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to [powershell `join-object` module](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/07/13/join-object/)? See also [more results here](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+join-object+module).